# Why wasn't there an investigation following Ariana Dumbledore's death?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

A girl is killed by magic in a wizard's household. Said girl never attended Hogwarts and there's nothing known about her, except that her mother, Kendra, also died in unclear circumstances not long ago. (Which case probably also wasn't investigated else Ariana would have taken to st. Mungo?)
Doesn't a death caused by magic merits an investigation, casting 
*priori incantatem* on the wands present at the time of the death, collecting their memories in pensives to track back the events?

Comment: Cool. Don't delete this: it will get closed in short order.